# Proving $\sum {\frac {ab}{ \left( a+b \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {\prod \left( a+b \right) }{16abc}}\geq \frac{5}{4}$

Tags: inequality, summation, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

For $a,b,c>0.$ Prove$:$
$${\frac {ab}{ \left( a+b \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {bc}{ \left( b+c
 \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {ac}{ \left( c+a \right) ^{2}}}+\,{\frac {
 \left( a+b \right)  \left( b+c \right)  \left( c+a \right) }{16abc}}\geqslant \frac{5}{4}$$
AM-GM kills it easy, but I think it's hard to get SOS$,$ I can't!

If $c=\min\{a,b,c\},$ we obtain the following by Maple$:$
[image]
However it's ugly. So I wish another SOS.

PS: This inequality is from Nguyen Viet Hung.

There is the AM-GM proof here: https://www.facebook.com/groups/1486244404996949/permalink/2695082927446418/

So I don't need the AM-GM proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SOS helps.

We need to prove that $$\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}{16abc}-\frac{1}{2}\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2}\right)$$ or
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}c(a-b)^2}{16abc}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{4(a+b)^2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\left(\frac{1}{ab}-\frac{4}{(a+b)^2}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^4}{ab(a+b)^2}\geq0.$$

Comment: WOW, very nice and simple SOS!

Comment: I still can't understand why me software does not give SOS for this.

Comment: Yeah, and I have upvote and accept it for you.

Comment: @tthnew There are many ways to write a polynomial in the SOS form. Just sometimes human make it a bit of better than computer.

Comment: Yes, this time my computer does not work. NguyenHuyen_AG give the longer SOS than you by computer.

Comment: Could you check my tag pqr info? https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/pqr/info . Thank you!

Comment: @tthnew I saw it. Basically, it's very good. But there are some mistakes. For example, you did not write all cases of equality occurring when $p$ and $r$ are constants. I'll fix your post in six months.

Comment: Thank you, Mike!

Comment: @tthnew Please do not unilaterally create tags. If you wish to create a tag for this topic, suggest it to the community through the [tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31103/12952) on meta.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber but I think pqr is an nice method for symmetric polynomials same as $uvw.$

Comment: @tthnew that's great but there is a process for creating new tags. See the meta thread.

Comment: I can't understand English much$,$ I will try to read it.